# Laravel vue js modal hide curret modal and show new modal with bootstrap 5

Tags: laravel, vue.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-5

I have 3 components in my vue js

```
create.vue
list-user.vue
modal-role.vue
```

in my `create.vue` i call the 2 other component,

```
<template>
  <div>
    <modal-role></modal-role>
    <list-user></list-user>
  </div>
</template
```

these 2 components are all modal

modal-role.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalRole">
            add members
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalRole" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalRoleLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalRoleLabel">Role</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li @click="selectRole(item)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalUser" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" v-for="item in roles" :key="item.id"> {{ item.name }} </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

list-user.vue

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalUser" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalUserLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" v-if="role">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalUserLabel">Choose members as {{ role.name }} </h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @click="dismiss()"></button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li 
                                class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" 
                                v-for="item in users" :key="item.id"
                            > 
                                {{ item.name + ' ' + item.surname}} 
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="row justify-content-center" v-if="!isLast">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="loadMore()">
                                View more
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" @click="dismiss()">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="choose()" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Choose</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So in my `create.vue` when i have button from my `modal-vue` to show a modal with list of role,
in `my modal-role.vue` what i expected is when i select one role, it dismiss the modal on `modal-role.vue` and show a new modal that is in `list-user.role` but I got an error:

```
app.js:14656 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at Object.findOne (app.js:14656:44)
    at Modal._showElement (app.js:16567:38)
    at app.js:16490:35
    at execute (app.js:13914:5)
    at app.js:16196:7
    at execute (app.js:13914:5)
    at HTMLDivElement.handler (app.js:13937:5)
```

and if tried to put the modal in `list-user.vue` to `modal-role.vue`, it work but if the second modal dismiss but i still have the overlay background from one of these 2 modals

**EDIT**

When i show the first modal,  got 2 modal backdrop in my element.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem here, i put a v-if in my modal-dialog div in my list-user.vue, so my modal have no div dialog in mounted then modal bootstrap can't call it to show, so i move my if statement in my modal-content and it work well